# How do I escape quotes in Node?

Tags: node.js

I would like to print a string like

```
"{"items": []}"

I tried: 

    "{\"items\": []}"
    '{\"items\": []}'
    "{\"items\": []}"
```

For some reason I am still getting this string

"{\"items\": []}"

I using the string as shown in the below code:

```
            if (res === null || res.items.length === 0) {
                context.res = {
                    status: 200,
                    body: {
                        message: "Cart is empty",
                        data: '"{"items": []}"' 
                    }
                };
                context.done();
            }
```

Also tried:

`{"items": []}` 
JSON.Stringify({items: []})

which is giving:

`"{\"items\": []}"`

Comment: How are you outputting the string?

Comment: '"{"items": []}"'

Comment: @Dai I am assigning it to an object and returning it.

Comment: @codedawi, it gave me "\"{\"items\": []}\"", this.

Comment: It's not a good practice to include a picture of code. Make an [edit] and type it out. Also, I dont see why the below answer will not work here.

Comment: According to the image you don't need to write your own json, it would stringify the body/object anyway. Also, you could simply do `data: JSON.stringify({items: []})`, but I dont think you even need to handle it yourself. XY Problem

Answer (score 1):

Use [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
`"{"items": []}"`
```

Comment: I got      "\"{\"items\": []}\""    this as output.

Comment: i have attached the image Pls,refer to it. Thanks

Comment: Use `\`` instead of `'`.